# How to split with '|' in perl

Tags: perl

the problem is that it return like split on undefined value

```
B
e
c
k
y
.
```

split string perl code

```
sub start_thread {
my @args = @_;
print('Thread started: ', @args, "\n");
open(my $myhandle,'<',@args) or die "unable to open file";  # typical open call
my @aftersplit;
for (;;) {
    while (<$myhandle>) {
    chomp;
    @aftersplit = split('|',$_);
    #print $_."\n";
    foreach my $val (@aftersplit){
       print $val."\n";
        }
    }
    sleep 1;
    seek FH, 0, 1;      # this clears the eof flag on FH
}
}
```

it split the string in $_ and save in array aftersplit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to escape `|` as it is special char in regex,

```
my @aftersplit = split(/\|/, $_);
```

Comment: IMHO, part of the confusion arises from the fact that the first argument is a regex PATTERN, not a string -- and hence special characters must be escaped -- and yet it's common to see single quotes.

Answer (score 3):

You need to escape special character `|` with `\`

```
@aftersplit = split('\|',$_);
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to escape your delimiter, since it's a special character.

For certain special characters you need to precede your character with a literal `\`

```
my @aftersplit = split '\|', $_;
```

You can also use [quotemeta](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/quotemeta.html).

```
my $separator = quotemeta('|');
my @aftersplit = split /$separator/, $_;
```

Or implement the escape sequence `\Q`

```
my @aftersplit = split /\Q|/, $_;
```